# Overloading post increment operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following program:

```
//Overloading post and pre incerement operator with and without member function
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test{
    int x,y;
    public:
    test (int a, int b){
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    void operator++ (int){
        (this->x)=(this->x)++;
        cout << "Value of x is" << x <<endl;
    }
    void showData(){
        cout << x <<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    test t1(9,10);
    t1.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

My doubt over here is that, after the line:
(this->x)=(this->x)++;

Shouldn't the value of x be incremented by 1, however on printing, it prints the value of x as 9 (and not 10)

Comment: I don't follow. Where are you calling the `++` operator on `t1`?

Comment: Just change `(this->x)=(this->x)++;` to `++x;` -- done.  Note that your operator overload should actually return a `test` object by value, not `void`.

Comment: `(this->x)=(this->x)++;` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M Can you please tell why is this undefined behavour?

Comment: @paddy I don't want to do pre increment, I want to do post increment

Comment: @paddy And regarding your second concern, the return type can be changed from void to test, but my doubt over here concerns post increment operator

Comment: @cigien I am calling post increment operator on t1 to increase the value of x of object by one.

Comment: You can not modify an object in two ways unsequenced (you increment `this->x` and also assign to it with the `=` operator). Paddy's suggestion is correct

Answer (score 2):

The post-fix increment like implemented by OP doesn't make much sense.

I would expect from a post-fix increment that it increments but returns the old value (in opposition to a pre-fix increment which returns the new value).

A post-fix increment operator should be usable in an expression. Hence, the return type `void` is an unlucky choice. If it returns `void` it can be used as statement only. Hence, there wouldn't be any visible difference between a pre-fix and a post-fix operator.

I suggest to change the return type to class type:

```cpp
    test operator++ (int){
        test old = *this;
        ++x; // or x++; It doesn't make a difference for int.
        return old;
    }
```

With this change, the following is possible:

```cpp
//Overloading post and pre incerement operator with and without member function
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test{
    int x,y;
    public:
    test (int a, int b){
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    test operator++ (int){
        test old = *this;
        ++x;
        return old;
    }
    void showData(std::ostream &out) const {
        out << x << ", " << y;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const test &t)
{
  t.showData(out);
  return out;
}

int main(){
    test t1(9,10);
    std::cout << t1 << endl;
    std::cout << t1++ << endl;
    std::cout << t1 << endl;
    t1++;
    std::cout << t1 << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
9, 10
9, 10
10, 10
11, 10
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/983b52dcb44cab53)